# Fetch Conversation Unread messages count

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have conversation schema and message schema. Message schema has conversationId. Each conversation has many messages. I want t fetch "n" number of conversations with it last message and total unread messages.
I am saving array for users who viewed message

```
viewedBy: [
    {
      user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
      }, // ID of the user who viewed the message
      timestamp: Date, // Timestamp when the message was viewed
    },
  ],
```

I have current user id as well. so if user already viewed this message their id will be their in viewedby
I have fetch all conversations with populate but i am not able to fetch last message and total unread message with this query.

```
    let doc = await Conversation.find({
    "participants.user": { $in: req.user._id },
  })
    .populate({
      path: "participants.user",
      select: "firstName middleName lastName profile primaryEmail role",
      populate: {
        path: "role",
        select: "name",
      },
    })
    .populate({
      path: "projectId",
      select: "id pitch",
      populate: {
        path: "pitch",
        select: "id title pitcherId",
        populate: {
          path: "pitcherId",
          select: "userId",
          populate: {
            path: "userId",
            select: "firstName middleName lastName profile primaryEmail role",
            populate: {
              path: "role",
              select: "name",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    })
    .sort({ updatedOn: "descending" })
    .limit(parseInt(itemsPerPage));
```

Then i try to use aggregatePipeline but i could not figure out how to get total unread messages and populate.

```
// let aggregatePipeline = [
  //   // Match conversations with the current user
  //   {
  //     $match: {
  //       "participants.user": { $in: [req.user._id] },
  //     },
  //   },
  //   // Lookup messages related to each conversation
  //   {
  //     $lookup: {
  //       from: "messages", // Assuming your Message model is named 'Message'
  //       localField: "_id",
  //       foreignField: "conversationId", // Adjust based on your actual field
  //       as: "messages",
  //     },
  //   },
  //   // Unwind the messages array
  //   {
  //     $unwind: "$messages",
  //   },
  //   // Match only the unread messages
  //   {
  //     $match: {
  //       "messages.viewedBy.user": req.user._id,
  //     },
  //   },
  //   // Group by conversationId and count the unread messages
  //   {
  //     $group: {
  //       _id: "$_id",
  //       unreadCount: { $sum: 1 },
  //     },
  //   },
  //   // Lookup the last message for each conversation
  //   {
  //     $lookup: {
  //       from: "messages",
  //       let: { conversationId: "$_id" },
  //       pipeline: [
  //         {
  //           $match: {
  //             $expr: { $eq: ["$conversationId", "$$conversationId"] },
  //           },
  //         },
  //         {
  //           $sort: { createdOn: -1 },
  //         },
  //         {
  //           $limit: 1,
  //         },
  //       ],
  //       as: "lastMessage",
  //     },
  //   },
  //   {
  //     $unwind: "$participants",
  //   },
  //   //Lookup participants.user
  //   {
  //     $lookup: {
  //       from: "users",
  //       localField: "participants.user",
  //       foreignField: "_id",
  //       as: "participants.user",
  //     },
  //   },
  //   {
  //     $group: {
  //       _id: "$_id",
  //       participants: { $addToSet: "$participants" }, // Use $addToSet to maintain as an array
  //       doc: {
  //         $mergeObjects: "$$ROOT",
  //       },
  //     },
  //   },
  //   {
  //     $replaceRoot: {
  //       newRoot: {
  //         $mergeObjects: ["$doc", { participants: "$participants" }],
  //       },
  //     },
  //   },
  //   {
  //     $set: {
  //       participants: {
  //         $map: {
  //           input: "$participants",
  //           as: "participant",
  //           in: {
  //             $mergeObjects: [
  //               "$$participant",
  //               {
  //                 user: {
  //                   $mergeObjects: [
  //                     { $arrayElemAt: ["$$participant.user", 0] },
  //                   ],
  //                 },
  //               },
  //             ],
  //           },
  //         },
  //       },
  //     },
  //   },
  //   {
  //     $unwind: "$participants",
  //   },
  //   {
  //     $lookup: {
  //       from: "roles",
  //       localField: "participants.user.role",
  //       foreignField: "_id",
  //       as: "participants.user.role",
  //     },
  //   },
  //   {
  //     $group: {
  //       _id: "$_id",
  //       participants: { $addToSet: "$participants" }, // Use $addToSet to maintain as an array
  //       doc: {
  //         $mergeObjects: "$$ROOT",
  //       },
  //     },
  //   },
  //   {
  //     $replaceRoot: {
  //       newRoot: {
  //         $mergeObjects: ["$doc", { participants: "$participants" }],
  //       },
  //     },
  //   },
  //   {
  //     $set: {
  //       participants: {
  //         $map: {
  //           input: "$participants",
  //           in: {
  //             $mergeObjects: [
  //               "$$this",
  //               {
  //                 user: {
  //                   $mergeObjects: [
  //                     "$$this.user",
  //                     { role: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$this.user.role", 0] } },
  //                   ],
  //                 },
  //               },
  //             ],
  //           },
  //         },
  //       },
  //     },
  //   },
  //   // //Lookup projectId
  //   // {
  //   //   $lookup: {
  //   //     from: "projects",
  //   //     localField: "projectId",
  //   //     foreignField: "_id",
  //   //     as: "projectId",
  //   //   },
  //   // },
  //   // //Unwind project array
  //   // {
  //   //   $unwind: "$projectId",
  //   // },
  //   // //Lookup project.pitch
  //   // {
  //   //   $lookup: {
  //   //     from: "pitches",
  //   //     localField: "projectId.pitch",
  //   //     foreignField: "_id",
  //   //     as: "projectId.pitch",
  //   //   },
  //   // },
  //   // //Unwind project.pitch array
  //   // {
  //   //   $unwind: "$projectId.pitch",
  //   // },
  //   // //Lookup project.pitch.pitcherId
  //   // {
  //   //   $lookup: {
  //   //     from: "pitchers",
  //   //     localField: "project.pitch.pitcherId",
  //   //     foreignField: "_id",
  //   //     as: "project.pitch.pitcherId",
  //   //   },
  //   // },
  //   // // Unwind project.pitch.pitcherId array
  //   // {
  //   //   $unwind: "$project.pitch.pitcherId",
  //   // },
  //   // {
  //   //   $lookup: {
  //   //     from: "users",
  //   //     localField: "project.pitch.pitcherId.userId",
  //   //     foreignField: "_id",
  //   //     as: "project.pitch.pitcherId.userId",
  //   //   },
  //   // },
  //   // {
  //   //   $unwind: "$project.pitch.pitcherId.userId",
  //   // },
  //   // {
  //   //   $lookup: {
  //   //     from: "roles",
  //   //     localField: "project.pitch.pitcherId.userId.role",
  //   //     foreignField: "_id",
  //   //     as: "project.pitch.pitcherId.userId.role",
  //   //   },
  //   // },
  //   // Project to reshape the output

  //   // Sort by the last message timestamp (descending order)
  //   {
  //     $sort: { "lastMessage.timestamp": -1 },
  //   },
  //   // Limit the number of results
  //   {
  //     $limit: parseInt(itemsPerPage),
  //   },
  // ];
```

> I want to fetch "n" number of conversations with its last message and total unread messages and populate all required properties.